# How to build an endpoint starting with Https in Retrofit?

Tags: android, https, retrofit

I can build an endpoint using http://, yet I have problem building an endpoint using https://.
I have created a new Api and Service for the Https:// one, yet there is always a RetrofitError occur to me. 
Any advice? Thx

Comment: Do you by any chance use self-signed SSL certificate?

Comment: Do you mean this one?
http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html
But how could I use the cert after generating it?

Comment: It's a part of server configuration.

Comment: Can you post a full logcat of the Retrofit error you are getting?